# Invalid use of Null error when splitting a String

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using VBA to run an access2010 form. There are Text boxes I have used the split function to divide into individual strings, and then I import these individual strings into a search form when I click the search button. If I enter text in each of the text boxes, the strings are imported as intended, but if none or even not all of them have a value entered, I get the error: Invalid use of Null. If I enter a value in each box and search, I can return to the previous form and clear the text boxes, and pull up the search form without a problem. Here is some of the code:

```
Private Sub Advanced_Search_btn_Click()
On Error GoTo Advanced_Search_btn_Click_Err
    Dim TitleArray() As String
    Dim TitleLength As Integer

    TitleArray() = Split(Title)     'Splits the textbox named title
    TitleLength = UBound(TitleArray) - LBound(TitleArray)
    If Trim(Title.Value & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then    'This is supposed 
        'to make nothing happen if nothing is in the text box, could be the problem
        Call TitleNone
    ElseIf TitleLength >= 5 Then
        Call Title5
    ElseIf TitleLength = 4 Then
        Call Title4
    ElseIf TitleLength = 3 Then
        Call Title3
    ElseIf TitleLength = 2 Then
        Call Title2
    ElseIf TitleLength = 1 Then
        Call Title1
    ElseIf TitleLength = 0 Then
        Call Title0
    Else
        Call TitleNone   'Sub to do nothing
    End If

    Sub TitleNone()
    End Sub

    TitleArray() = Split(Title)   'Example of string import
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title] = TitleArray(0)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 2] = TitleArray(1)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 3] = TitleArray(2)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 4] = TitleArray(3)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 5] = TitleArray(4)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 6] = TitleArray(5)
End Sub
```

Anyway, I hope this is enough information to see what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

EDIT: I came up with a way to make it work, I just added extra subs to do the job, posting for anyone who encounters a similar problem:
    Private Sub Advanced_Search_btn_Click()
    Dim TitleArray() As String
    Dim TitleLength As Integer
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Advanced Search", acNormal, "", "", , acNormal

```
If Not IsNull(Me.Title.Value) Then
TitleArray() = Split(Title)
TitleLength = UBound(TitleArray) - LBound(TitleArray)
Call TitleCall
End If

Sub TitleCall()
Dim TitleArray() As String
Dim TitleLength As Integer
TitleArray() = Split(Title)
TitleLength = UBound(TitleArray) - LBound(TitleArray)
If TitleLength >= 5 Then
Call Title5
ElseIf TitleLength = 4 Then
Call Title4
ElseIf TitleLength = 3 Then
Call Title3
ElseIf TitleLength = 2 Then
Call Title2
ElseIf TitleLength = 1 Then
Call Title1
ElseIf TitleLength = 0 Then
Call Title0
Else
Call TitleNone
End If
End Sub

Sub Title5()
Dim TitleArray() As String
TitleArray() = Split(Title)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title] = TitleArray(0)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 2] = TitleArray(1)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 3] = TitleArray(2)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 4] = TitleArray(3)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 5] = TitleArray(4)
    Forms![Advanced Search]![Title Keyword 6] = TitleArray(5)

Sub TitleNone()
End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show actual code. This will not compile for many reasons.

Comment: `TitleLength = UBound(TitleArray) - LBound(TitleArray)` A single-element array has lbound=ubound=0 (unless using `Option Base 1`), so your math is missing a `+1` here

Comment: I understand that if there's only a single word the length will be 0, can you expand on how this is a problem?

Comment: Please update your code. As of now, it is not valid, compilable VBA. You seem to have an embedded sub in another sub.

Comment: I guess it's not really a problem (having now read the rest of the code) but it's confusing to use a variable named "TitleLength" in a way which appears to be calculating the length of the array, when in fact it's "length minus one".